# MySQL Workbench Export of data (Schema Lost!!)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I exported my database in MySQL Workbench, because I had to recreate the database. I dropped the schema, and now when I try import the schema, there is nothing there. If anyone can help me retrieve the schema I will be very grateful.

Either I don't understand MySQL Workbench, or the data was not exported correctly.

Steps I followed in MySQL Workbench:

1. Server -> Data Export -> I selected the relevant schema (www) -> Export to Self-Contained File -> Start Export
2. Check that the file exists (Database_schema_1.sql).
3. Selected the Schema -> Drop Schema
4. Server -> Data Import -> Import Self-Contained File -> Select Database_schema_1.sql

The schema is not there!!!

[image]

Does anyone know if I can retrieve the schema please?

(I am using Windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

Recovered it.

During the import, I selected a `New...` Default Target Schema, and named it the name (`www`) of the schema I exported.